# VS 2012 naming mangling still applied to dll exports

Tags: winapi, dll, dllexport

Why is name mangling still applied to `func3()`'s signature. 
What am I missing? I've reviewed these previously asked questions [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13648951/visual-studio-2008-release-build-not-decorating-dll-exports), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8874036/why-are-the-exported-functions-not-named-properly-in-the-dll) 
NO DEF files are being referenced.

```
// dllmain.cpp
#include "stdafx.h"

extern "C"  __declspec( dllexport ) double __cdecl func1(int id, double t)
{
    return(1.01);
};

extern "C" __declspec( dllexport ) int __cdecl func2(int id)
{
    return(2);
};

extern "C" __declspec( dllexport ) int __cdecl func3(char* file)
{
    return(1);
};

......
```

---

Here's output from `dumpbin /EXPORTS`:

```
    00000000 characteristics
    51B78F5E time date stamp Tue Jun 11 13:58:06 2013
        0.00 version
           1 ordinal base
           3 number of functions
           3 number of names

    ordinal hint RVA      name

          1    0 00003870 func1 = func1
          2    1 00003880 func2 = func2
          3    2 00001A00 func3 = ?do_encoding@codecvt_base@std@@MEBAHXZ (protected: virtual int __cdecl std::codecvt_base::do_encoding(void)const )
```

Comment: Very strange, I don't think it should be. Do you also have a header file where the function is declared without C linkage?

Comment: Try changing func3 name to func30

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The exports are not mangled, you can clearly see the unmangled name in the dumpbin.exe output.  You *also* see the mangled name.  That's dumpbin.exe being a bit too helpful, perhaps, it also reads the .pdb file to find the actual name of the function.  It displays it on the right-hand side of the =

Simply delete the .pdb file and run dumpbin.exe again to see the difference.

You don't have a problem, it worked.